# Push JSON file with special chars unicode to bigquery via command line

Tags: json, google-bigquery, bq, bq-load

Im trying to push a json file to BQ via bqcmd which contains special chars such as ü but tis failing. Ive tried differnt encoding etc. nothing workign except removing the chars

```
 {
    "productName": "soft drüum",
    "Category": "xxxxxxx",
    "subCategory": "Sun & Tan",
    "subSubCategory": "Sun",
    "productType": "Standard",
    "brandName": "soft drüum",
    "quantity": 1
}
```

Json File was successful until introduction of special chars

BQ command:

```
bq load --autodetect=true --time_partitioning_field date
--source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON Data.products D:\XXXX\xx\products.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check to make sure that you have your json saved as new line delimited. In  your example, the trailing comma is not valid in New Line Delimited JSON.

I was able to then upload these special characters via this command:

```sh
bq load --project_id=${project_id} --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect ${database}.${table} ${nldjson_filename}
```

Comment: Apologies that trailing comma does not exist have removed it...Really you got it uploaded? i am using that exact bq command.. The newline delimited JSON file upload always worked but broke due to the introduction of the special chars

Comment: You definitley get the ü char uploaded?

Comment: BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'xx-xxx-xxxxxxy-
eu:bqjob_r1733e0c139aa0cd5_0000017eb64ed348_1': Error while reading data, error
message: Failed to parse JSON: Expected , or } after key:value pair; Parser
terminated before end of string